# Symfony can't detect the roles from FOSUser

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, roles

I am setting up the user management for a website with FOSUser for the first time and I'm having some trouble figuring out where I mess up.

The role is in the database, in the `roles` column, like this:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";}
```

When I do a `var_dump($this->getUser())` from the controller, I get this:

```
(...)
["roles":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "ROLE_ADMIN" }
(...)
```

So everything's fine over here too.

When I try either `if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))` from the controller or `{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}` from a twig template, Symfony doesn't detect the role. The profiler also tells me there is only the `ROLE_USER` role.

Here is my `app/config/security.yml` file:

```
security:
    providers:
        main:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    encoders:
        Site\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_MODERATOR: [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_MODERATOR]

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
            logout:
                path: fos_user_security_logout
                target: /
            remember_me:
                key: %secret%

        default:
            anonymous: ~
```

Comment: Do you have `getRoles()` method in your Entity class?

Comment: ROLE_USER gets automatically added by FOSUserBundle without being persisted, so the absence of other Roles makes it look like there's some mismatch between your persisted User object and the bundle.  How did you add that ROLE_ADMIN to the DB?

Comment: Have you got this in config.yml?: `user_class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User`

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov : I don't have `getRoles()`, but my `User` extends the base User from FOS. I don't know if that User has a `getRoles()`.

Comment: @frumious : Yes, the `fos_user.user_class` is well defined in my config file.

Comment: Did you clear your cache? For `prod` and for `dev`?

Comment: Thank you @MichaelSivolobov, now I feel dumb for not applying the most basic Symfony rule: "when you have an unexpected bug, clear the cache". Please change your comment to an answer so I can reward you with some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't clear the cache. Try to clear cache for your environment

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod #for prod env
```

or

```
php app/console cache:clear #for dev env
```

Answer (score 0):

To help confused passers-by:

In case you have followed the Symfony security tutorial at http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#create-your-user-entity, you may have implemented a method like this:

```
public function getRoles()
{
    return array('ROLE_USER');
}
```

If you have switched to `FOSUserBundle` later on, you may have forgotten to remove this method. For me, this was the (home-made) issue why my users' roles didn't load properly.

Answer (score -1):

If i am not confuse then you have in your line in security.yml

```
        role_hierarchy:
            ROLE_MODERATOR: [ROLE_USER]
            ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_MODERATOR]
```

which describe that in both roles you have entered the value

> ROLE_USER

so you should do like following lines

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_MODERATOR:   [ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_MODERATOR,ROLE_ADMIN]
```

Comment: Don't think so.  Questionner's config looks OK if you want a ROLE_USER role, a ROLE_MODERATOR which also has ROLE_USER, and a ROLE_ADMIN which has ROLE_MODERATOR and ROLE_USER.  They've assigned ROLE_ADMIN and then tested ROLE_ADMIN, so hierarchy should be independent of this issue.